# Try multiple AP's and Passwords until connected on ESP32 with micropython

Tags: wifi, esp32, micropython

I would like for my ESP32 running micropython to keep trying four different AP's until one of them connects. The following gives a `no AP found` error.

```
import esp32
from machine import Pin, ADC, reset

SSID1 = "firstAP"
PASSWORD1 = "letmein"
SSID2 = "secondAp"
PASSWORD2 = "letmein"
SSID3 = "thirdAP"
PASSWORD3 = "letmein"
SSID4 = "fourthAP"
PASSWORD4 = "letmein"

def do_connect():
    import network
    sta_if = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        sta_if.active(True)        
        sta_if.connect(SSID1, PASSWORD1)
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            pass  
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        sta_if.active(True)        
        sta_if.connect(SSID2, PASSWORD2)
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            pass  
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        sta_if.active(True)        
        sta_if.connect(SSID3, PASSWORD3)
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            pass  
    if not sta_if.isconnected():
        print('connecting to network...')
        sta_if.active(True)        
        sta_if.connect(SSID4, PASSWORD4)
        while not sta_if.isconnected():
            pass  
    print('network config:', sta_if.ifconfig())

do_connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not 'hands on' with the ESP32 port of Micropython  but in the pyboard port you can use the WLAN.scan() command to scan for the available wireless networks from a WLAN STA instance.

The scan returns a list of tuples with the information about WiFi access points it finds: (ssid, bssid, channel, RSSI, authmode, hidden).

bssid is hardware address of an access point, in binary form, returned as bytes object. You can use ubinascii.hexlify() to convert it to ASCII form.

You should then be able to use that list of tuples to find the network you want.

I'll try and dig up some code to demonstrate it.

Added examples:

```
nets = wlan.scan()
for net in nets:
    if net.ssid == 'mywifi':
        print('Network found!')
        wlan.connect(net.ssid, auth=(net.sec, 'mywifikey'), timeout=5000)
        while not wlan.isconnected():
            machine.idle() # save power while waiting
        print('WLAN connection succeeded!')
        break
```

or

```
import os
import machine

uart = machine.UART(0, 115200)
os.dupterm(uart)

known_nets = {
    '<net>': {'pwd': '<password>'},
    '<net>': {'pwd': '<password>', 'wlan_config':  ('10.0.0.114', '255.255.0.0', '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.1')}, # (ip, subnet_mask, gateway, DNS_server)
}

if machine.reset_cause() != machine.SOFT_RESET:
    from network import WLAN
    wl = WLAN()
    wl.mode(WLAN.STA)
    original_ssid = wl.ssid()
    original_auth = wl.auth()

    print("Scanning for known wifi nets")
    available_nets = wl.scan()
    nets = frozenset([e.ssid for e in available_nets])

    known_nets_names = frozenset([key for key in known_nets])
    net_to_use = list(nets & known_nets_names)
    try:
        net_to_use = net_to_use[0]
        net_properties = known_nets[net_to_use]
        pwd = net_properties['pwd']
        sec = [e.sec for e in available_nets if e.ssid == net_to_use][0]
        if 'wlan_config' in net_properties:
            wl.ifconfig(config=net_properties['wlan_config'])
        wl.connect(net_to_use, (sec, pwd), timeout=10000)
        while not wl.isconnected():
            machine.idle() # save power while waiting
        print("Connected to "+net_to_use+" with IP address:" + wl.ifconfig()[0])

    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed to connect to any known network, going into AP mode")
        wl.init(mode=WLAN.AP, ssid=original_ssid, auth=original_auth, channel=6, antenna=WLAN.INT_ANT)
```

Hope this is of some help to you, you may need to make minor changes to code of course.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered adding each connect attempt inside a `try:` statement? From what it seems to me your code tries to connect to the first SSID, it can't find it and it throws the error.

try something like this:

```
if not sta_if.isconnected():
    print('connecting to network...')
    try:
        sta_if.active(True)        
        sta_if.connect(SSID1, PASSWORD1)
    except:
        print("SSID not found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
import network

# Set up the Wi-Fi networks you want to try to connect to
networks = [("SSID1", "PSK1"), ("SSID2", "PSK2")]

# Attempt to connect to each network in order
for ssid, psk in networks:
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, psk)

    # Wait for the connection to succeed or fail
    for _ in range(20):
        if wlan.isconnected():
            print("Connected to", ssid)
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)

    # If we successfully connected to a network, stop trying
    if wlan.isconnected():
        break
```